# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY : smartwatch app

Tags: android, eclipse, sony, failed-installation, sony-smartwatch

I want to make a smartwach app.

I used the instructions on this site:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/how-to-create-an-app-extension-for-sony-smartwatch-2/

I want to run the app in my phone with the usb cable, like in the website above.

This the output from the console:

```
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] ------------------------------
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] Android Launch!
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] adb is running normally.
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] No Launcher activity found!
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] The launch will only sync the application package on  the device!
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] Performing sync
 [2014-04-06 09:54:21 - SmallAppSample] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device  compatibility. Please select a target device.
 [2014-04-06 09:54:23 - SmallAppSample] Uploading SmallAppSample.apk onto device   '022AQQ7N3B075241'
 [2014-04-06 09:54:24 - SmallAppSample] Installing SmallAppSample.apk...
 [2014-04-06 09:54:25 - SmallAppSample] Installation error:          INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
 [2014-04-06 09:54:25 - SmallAppSample] Please check logcat output for more details.
 [2014-04-06 09:54:25 - SmallAppSample] Launch canceled!
```

logcat :

```
04-06 11:08:24.402: W/GAV2(7597): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Exception sending hit:     HttpHostConnectException
04-06 11:08:24.402: W/GAV2(7597): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Connection to     https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
04-06 11:08:25.785: E/PGPSDownloader.SocketServer(11287): java.io.IOException:     Connection refused
04-06 11:08:26.792: I/android_hardware_fm.cpp(12096): ----Inside int     register_android_hardware_fm_fmradio(JNIEnv*)----
04-06 11:08:26.792: I/android_hardware_fm.cpp(12096):     register_android_hardware_fm_fmradio, ret is 0
04-06 11:08:27.148: W/System.err(12106): java.io.FileNotFoundException:     /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at     libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>    (FileInputStream.java:109)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at     android.content.res.ResourcesEx.readDefaultConfig(ResourcesEx.java:808)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.<init>    (ResourcesEx.java:741)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1721)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1752)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:485)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1911)
04-06 11:08:27.152: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1904)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4269)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
04-06 11:08:27.155: W/System.err(12106):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-06 11:08:27.158: W/System.err(12106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
04-06 11:08:27.158: W/System.err(12106): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open     failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-06 11:08:27.162: W/System.err(12106):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-06 11:08:27.162: W/System.err(12106):    at     libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-06 11:08:27.162: W/System.err(12106):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
04-06 11:08:27.162: W/System.err(12106):    ... 19 more
04-06 11:08:27.438: W/System.err(6666): java.io.FileNotFoundException:     /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-06 11:08:27.438: W/System.err(6666):     at     libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
04-06 11:08:27.438: W/System.err(6666):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>    (FileInputStream.java:109)
04-06 11:08:27.438: W/System.err(6666):     at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.readDefaultConfig(ResourcesEx.java:808)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.<init>    (ResourcesEx.java:741)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1721)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1752)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at     android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.    java:746)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at     android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:970)
04-06 11:08:27.442: W/System.err(6666):     at     android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:118)
04-06 11:08:27.445: W/System.err(6666):     at     com.google.android.vending.verifier.PackageVerificationService.getPackageInfo(PackageVerifi    cationService.java:564)
04-06 11:08:27.445: W/System.err(6666):     at     com.google.android.vending.verifier.PackageVerificationService.access$100(PackageVerificati    onService.java:49)
04-06 11:08:27.448: W/System.err(6666):     at         com.google.android.vending.verifier.PackageVerificationService$WorkerTask.doInBackground(Pa    ckageVerificationService.java:282)
04-06 11:08:27.448: W/System.err(6666):     at     com.google.android.vending.verifier.PackageVerificationService$WorkerTask.doInBackground(Pa    ckageVerificationService.java:232)
04-06 11:08:27.448: W/System.err(6666):     at     04-06 11:08:27.452:     W/System.err(6666):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-06 11:08:27.455: W/System.err(6666):     at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-06 11:08:27.455: W/System.err(6666):     at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-06 11:08:27.455: W/System.err(6666):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-06 11:08:27.458: W/System.err(6666): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open     failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-06 11:08:27.462: W/System.err(6666):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-06 11:08:27.462: W/System.err(6666):     at     libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-06 11:08:27.465: W/System.err(6666):     at     libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
04-06 11:08:27.465: W/System.err(6666):     ... 17 more
04-06 11:08:27.502: I/qtaguid(6666): Failed write_ctrl(u 51) res=-1 errno=22
04-06 11:08:27.502: I/qtaguid(6666): Untagging socket 51 failed errno=-22
04-06 11:08:27.502: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(6666): untagSocket(51) failed with     errno -22
04-06 11:08:27.512: I/ElegantRequestDirector(6666): I/O exception     (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server     failed to respond
04-06 11:08:27.515: I/ElegantRequestDirector(6666): Retrying request
04-06 11:08:35.788: E/PGPSDownloader.SocketServer(11287): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
```

Comment: can you post your LogCat output as well ?

Comment: added logcat, thanks for responding

Comment: hello can you please respond?

Comment: //I don't understand the log completely but it seems like a library/file is missing. Do you have SmartWatch app already installed ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere ? resolved something ?

Comment: Yes, I have the smartwatch app installed and i can install smartwatch apps from the apps store. Maybe my android version is not compatible with the addon , my android is 4.2.2 and for the app you need 4.1.2 so that is not a problem i think.

Comment: Hi , I found someone with the same problem here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819114/sony-smartwatch-application

Comment: I have reinstalled eclipse and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. make a libs/ folder
2. delete in your Manifest file the used-libraries

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
My solution was to remove the

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />
```

from the SmallAppSample Manifest