# Where do I get the shared library " com.sony.smallapp.framework" from?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, sony, sony-smartwatch

I strarted developing an app that uses Sony Smartwatch 2 as an "secondary screen".
Therefore I had a look to the sample apps that come with Sonys Add-on SDK 3.0 but I dint not get all of them to work because shared library " com.sony.smallapp.framework" is missing .

For example:  
If I want to execute "*ActionDelegatorDemo*" on the Smartphone/Watch  
I get Installation error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

LogCat tells me:

> Package com.example.sonymobile.smallapp.actiondelegatordemo requires unavailable shared library com.sony.smallapp.framework; failing!

I tried to run it on Nexus 5 and Galxy S4 connected to SmartWatch 2. The app "SmartConnect" is installed and connectetd to the watch. But I had always the same error.

The following Packages are installed in my SDK-Manager:
*"Sony Add-on SDK 3.0" API19, Rev 1

"Sony DeviceProfiles" Rev.5*

In Properties-> Android-> Project Build Targed: "Sony Add-on  SDK 3.0" is selected

Java Build Path includes the "Sony Add-on  SDK 3.0 [Android 4.4.2]" too.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

---

BTW: I already read:
[Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY : smartwatch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891744/installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library-smartwatch-app)

If I remove "" from the manifest I get an error on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to what teepee said above.  Seems you are trying to run the wrong sample apps.

For SW2 you should be running the samples in the /samples/SmartExtensions folder.  Small Apps is something completely unrelated to SW2.

Answer (score 0):

SmartWatch2 apps don't use SmallApp framework at all. So remove all the links and references to that library.